# Are these sets homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology

> Are $X_1 = \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ and $X_2 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 0 < ||x||<1 \}$ homeomorphic? Is $X_2$ homeomorphic to $X_3 = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^2: 1 < ||x|| < 2 \}?$

I want to say that they are, but I'm having trouble writing down an explicit homeomorphism $f_1:X_1 \to X_2$ and $f_2:X_2 \to X_3.$ How do we construct functions $f_1,f_2$ between these sets such that $f_1,f_2$ are continuous, bijective and have continuous inverses? Any hints appreciated

Comment: I know an homeomorphism need to be a bijection (and other things). How is it possible to state a bijection between $X_1$ y $X_2$ if they have different dimension?

Comment: Do you mean $\{x \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < \| x\| <1\}$?

Comment: In that case, do you also mean $X_3=\{x \in \mathbb R^2 : 0 < \| x\| <2\}$?

Comment: @JohnMa Yes, sorry about the typo

Comment: In that case, for $f_1$ make use of the $tan$ function and for $f_2$ make use of a re-scale.

Answer (score 8):

Hint: In terms or polar coordinate, you need only to find a homeomorphism

$$(0, \infty) \cong (0,1) \cong (1,2).$$

Answer (score 2):

**CW**: This is merely expanding on John Ma's hint in case someone/someday/somewhere reads it and is not quite sure what is meant.

Focusing just on the first quadrant, viewed as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}$:

The open interval $(0,1)$ can be mapped to $(1,2)$ by the homeomorphism $x \mapsto x+1$.

(I'm guessing that wasn't where you struggled.)

Next, we seek a homeomorphism between the open interval $(0, \infty)$ and $(0, 1)$.

How about mapping the former to the latter using the homeomorphism $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$?

Great; now spin around!

Concretely, to show, e.g., $X_1$ and $X_2$ are homeomorphic:

Given a point in $X_1$, rotate it $\rho$ degrees onto the axis in the first quadrant; then map it to $(0,1)$ using $x \mapsto \frac{x}{x+1}$; then rotate it back by $-\rho$ degrees so that it lands comfortably in $X_2$.

This composition of homeomorphisms gives a homeomorphism $X_1 \rightarrow X_2$, and hopefully the remaining details/verification are all well within reach.